# Generate Excel files from an attribute table using a certain field

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, excel

I have got a table with many fields, where one of them is the main one, as they are sectors of a region in Spain (Comunidad Autónoma, in Spanish). I know I can export that table to Excel from ArcGIS or QGIS, and even if I filter by those sectors I could do it individually, but it would be a lot or work as they are more than 50 sectors. Is there any way or tool to generate those 50 Excel files from a field?

Comment: Please, add some sample data (or a screenshot, if you cannot disclose the source files) and specify more clearly what you want to do, as just like this, this question seems unsalvageable. For future reference, please, post in English.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. By specifying both QGIS and ArcGIS for solutions, you are asking two questions. Please choose one and make an attempt. Then you'll have the necessary level of detail (or it might just work for you)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python. Find all unique values, iterate over them in a for loop, extract by attribute:

```py
import os
out_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/excels/" #Adjust
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("municipality")[0]
sector_field = "lanskod" #My grouping field, adjust
uniquevals = {f[sector_field] for f in layer.getFeatures()}
for val in uniquevals:
    filename = f"export_{val}.xlsx"
    output = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
    print(filename)
    processing.run("native:extractbyattribute", 
    {'INPUT':layer,'FIELD':sector_field,'OPERATOR':0,
    'VALUE':str(val),'OUTPUT':output})
```

[image]